# Zorp vs. Zorp GPL - what are all the differences?

Tags: proxy

https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Zorp_firewall

"The GPL version is completely usable and functional, however it lacks some of the more advanced functions available in the commercially available version only."

Question: What are those advanced functions?